# How to link all tables together?

Tags: sql

I need to list countries in which there are customers, the number of
customers, the number of orders, and the total amount of money spent by customers from the country. Using w3school database, I calculated separately each country, number of customers, number of orders and total amount spent, but I don't know how to link all together.

I have just started to study SQL.

Table for number of customers:

```
SELECT country, count(*) as 'number of customer' 
FROM [Customers]
group by country
```

Number of orders by country:

```
SELECT Country, count(*) as 'number of order' 
FROM Orders, Customers
where orders.customerID=customers.CustomerID
group by country
```

Total amount spent by country:

```
SELECT Country, sum(price*quantity) as 'total price paid' 
FROM Orders, Customers, orderDetails, Products
where orders.customerID=customers.CustomerID 
and orders.OrderID=orderDetails.OrderID 
and orderDetails.productID=products.ProductID
group by country
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must learn to use proper joins (using the `JOIN` keyword and an `ON` clause) and not this old style (using the `WHERE` clause).
 
Also it's a good practice to alias the tables.
Now you have to join all the tables and count the distinct values of the columns like this:

```
SELECT 
  c.Country, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers WHERE Country = c.Country) as 'number of customer',
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID) as 'number of order' 
  SUM(od.price * od.quantity) as 'total price paid' 
FROM Customers c 
INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN orderDetails od ON ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products p ON od.productID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY c.Country
```

I used the qualifier `od` for `price` and `quantity` because I believe that they are coluns of the table `orderDetails`. 
Or with `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT 
  c.Country, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.customerID) as 'number of customer',
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID) as 'number of order' 
  COALESCE(SUM(od.price * od.quantity), 0) as 'total price paid' 
FROM Customers c 
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
LEFT JOIN orderDetails od ON ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
LEFT JOIN Products p ON od.productID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY c.Country
```

Comment: thank you I did some changes it works for order number and total price but still not count the Number of Customers

Comment: I can't tell why you don't get the number of customers especially if you changed the code. `COUNT(DISTINCT c.customerID)` is the way to go because it counts all the distinct customers for each country.

Comment: I think I need the number of customers in the country not the number of customer who ordered in the country

Comment: thank you it work with Left join, but what is coalesce you input what does mean?many thanks. and could you advise me a good website I can practice?

Comment: I use coalesce() just in case the  customer does not have any orders and the sum will be returned as null to return 0 instead of null. I can't recommend any particular site but if in the site you do this practice they teach the joins like you wrote them in the question with WHERE then you should probably leave it.

Comment: @Dezdi if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.